# Is it safe to kill and uninstall sqlserver.exe?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, sql-server

I am a student who mainly works with Visual Studio/Visual Studio Code/Emacs. I think the SQL server was installed with visual studio. I don't really do anything related to SQL servers and especially Microsoft SQL servers (last time I used their SQL management tool was a year ago when I was going through my first DB course).
I was looking at the control panel and it seems like there are a lot of things installed in its name and I was thinking I should clean it up. Is it safe to uninstall it or is it necessary for something that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: probably not.

Long answer: depends.

A very surprising number of things use the local SQL server, not just conventional databases.

I would recommend setting it to run as needed, then reboot, do some test work and make sure it doesn't break the things you normally do.  This should be a fire and forget option so that if you do need it the server will start but it won't always be running.

If all goes well this should slow the start of things that need it, but shouldn't break anything.  Of course, sometimes things don't work the way they should so keep an eye out for any issue resulting from the inability to contact the SQL server.

You definitely should not just terminate it blindly, nor would I recommend uninstalling it. This is far more likely to break stuff, and do so badly.

Answer (score 0):

For the average user, COMPLETELY safe to uninstall.

You 'could' do all of the stuff in the other answer.. it wouldn't hurt.. but it would waste quite a bit of your time.

I don't install it in the first place.. and if I accidentally did, I would uninstall.

Even visual studio itself uses SQLite for it's internal .vs store.

***WORST CASE***.. (pretending I am wrong.. which I am not) you could reinstall it via add/remove in the visual studio installer.  It's not like it is "dangerous" to get a "cant connect" error. :P